# unable to see all the records from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a User model with just name, email and password. I populated the sqllite db with 100 users and on doing User.all i can see those 100 users on rails console.

However, In my app I do not see it. Unable to understand the issue please advise. 
Code:

Routes.rb

```
match '/users', to:'users#index'
```

users_controller.rb

```
def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

users\index.html.rb

```
 <%
     if(@users)
     @users.each do |user| %>
      <li>
        <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
      </li>
  <% end
  end %>
```

Comment: Need more info: What *do* you see; is there an error?  For starters, your view should have extension .html.erb.

Comment: Also, in your view try `raise @users.to_yaml`. Does this return anything?

Comment: Tim i dont see any error. it just does not render all the users which kind of indicates that may be it is not fetching the users and returning null

Comment: I will give a ry Sabar if it returns something as you sugessted

Comment: hi Sabar it does not return anything at all. Actually the page fails to come up on adding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the exact issue but redoing the same steps again worked from my from the tutorial on rubyonrails.org